# How to compare two variables containing ipv6 addresses?

Tags: bash, string

I have to compare two variables with ipv6 so there are strings and integers together.

I tried it as below:

```
if [[ "$ipvsrc" -eq "$ipvdst" ]];
       then echo -e "Value OK";  fi
```

error output was:

```
line 7: [[: 2a00: value too great for base (error token is "2a00")
```

Then:

```
if [ $ipvsrc -eq $ipvdst];
       then echo -e "Value OK";  fi
```

error output was:

```
line 7: [: 2a00:0da9:000a:2010:1fc:0:2174:1951: integer expression expected
```

Then:

```
if [[ "$ipvsrc" == "$ipvdst" ]];
       then echo -e "Value OK";
fi
```

output: none

Variables are set as following:

```
ipvsrc=$(cat config_src | grep ipvsrc |grep -v localhost | cut -d '=' -f2);

ipvdst=$(cat config_dst | grep -i ipvdst | cut -d '=' -f2);
```

Any hints gents how to get a desired output ?
Many thanks cheers!

Comment: I assume the shell is `bash`?

Comment: yes, it's `bash`

Comment: Nit picks: (1) `-eq` is __numeric__ comparison, while `==` is __string__ comparison.  (2) In `[[...]]` you should use `==`, while in `[...]` you have to use `=` (actually `==` in `[...]` is also supported by `bash`, but is not portable).  (3) `cat file | grep foo` is (much) better written as `grep foo file`.

Comment: FYI, piping `cat` into `grep` and then `grep` again and then into `cut` is not necessary.  try `ipvsrc=$(awk -F'=' '! /localhost/ && /ipvsrc/ {print $2}')`

Answer (score 1):

Your last example is correct (assuming you use a shell like `bash` or `ksh93` that understands `[[ ... ]]`, but it seems that you do):

```
if [[ "$ipvsrc" == "$ipvdst" ]]; then
    echo "Value OK";
fi
```

The two variables that you compare contains strings, so quoting them and using `==` is correct.

The reason you're getting no output is probably simply because the comparison evaluates to false, i.e. that the two strings are not identical.

Unfortunately, I do not know the contents of `config_{src,dst}`, so I can not tell what the values of the two variable is likely to be, or if they should be the same or different from each other.

Comment: well, these two values are identical.
is there a chance that the way how variables are defined is not readable by bash ?

Comment: They are just two strings, `bash` doesn't care what's in them. Print them out on the screen with `echo "ipvsrc: '$ipvsrc', ipvdst: '$ipvdst'"` and see if they are what you think they are. Look for extra spaces etc.